# Plural von einzelnen Buchstaben

Tags: grammatical-number

Wie bildet man korrekt die Mehrzahl von einzelnen Buchstaben, so wie in:

> Da die ersten l Zeichen von x nur **as** sind, ...

Wenn das so formuliert ist, wird nicht klar, dass das **s** in **as** ein Plural-s ist.

Eine andere Möglichkeit wäre auch noch **a's**.

Comment: Related: [What gender are the letters?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17689/what-gender-are-the-letters)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Der Plural eines Buchstabens ist der Buchstabe: Im letzten Satz kamen drei U vor. Den Buchstaben schreibst du am besten groß.

[Siehe auch z.B. hier (link)](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/ein-u--zwei-us-).

Comment: Wie schon auf GuteFrage.net jemand sowie @userunknown richtig schreibt, ist es durchaus auch üblich, den _s_-Plural für Buchstaben zu verwenden, außer bei S und X. Den würde ich schriftsprachlich allerdings nur verwenden, wenn ich den Buchstabennamen ausschreibe: _As, Ces, Effs, Kus, Vaus, Ypsilons, Zetts_.

Answer (score 2):

Der Buchstabe A ist ein Substantiv und muss daher großgeschrieben werden.

Die Mehrzahl von A ist A (ugs.: As). Der Plural wird im Deutschen (und auch im Englischen) nie mit Apostroph gebildet. Der Apostroph ist ein Auslassungszeichen.

Es gibt eine falsche Scheu die A in x großzuschreiben, wenn x *der Saal* ist, weil die A in *Saal* ja auch kleingeschrieben werden. Aber wenn man es vorliest, hört man eh nicht, ob das A groß- oder kleingeschrieben wird.

Will man Zweideutigkeiten wie die A in Aachen handhaben, muss man auch beim Sprechen einen Unterschied machen, der über die Schreibung hinausgeht. Das ist nicht schwer, man sagt einfach "Das kleine A" oder "Das große A". Bei Harald Schmitt auch "Das gute A". (see Youtube).

Answer (score 1):

Wie wäre es, einfach den Satz selbst ein bisschen eindeutiger zu gestalten? Beispielsweise so:

> Da die ersten l Zeichen von x nur der Buchstabe "A" sind, ...

Ansonsten gilt (wie oben erwähnt): "Der Plural eines Buchstaben ist der Buchstabe."

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde das Problem umgehen und schreiben "In dem Wort kommt der Buchstabe a dreimal vor".

Comment: Das ist eher keine Option, wenn man formal von Wörtern spricht (Wörter wie "aaab" gegenüber "aaba").

Comment: Wenn ich sage in Alabaster kommt a dreimal vor - was gefällt dir daran nicht?

Comment: Das ist funktioniert super in diesem Kontext, der Satz gefällt mir.