# What gender are the letters?

Tags: gender

I want to say that the stress on the word "Banane" falls on the second 'a'. What's the gender of 'a'?

> Die/Der/Das zweite "a" wird im Wort "Banane" betont.

Which one is correct?

Comment: "Ich kaufe ein 'a'." http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/a_Buchstabe_Ton

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nominalised single letters are neuter:

> das A
>   das B
>   das C
>   das D
>   …

However, the letter case of individual letters of a word is not changed:

> das a in Land
>   das b in Abend
>   das c in Tacitus
>   das d in Bude
>   …

On the other hand, the word „Buchstabe“ is masculine:

> der Buchstabe A
>   der Buchstabe B
>   der Buchstabe C
>   der Buchstabe D
>   …

Comment: Additionally note, that digits are typically female (*die Drei*) and punctuation have no universal rule. (*Das Komma* aber *der* Punkt).

Comment: Auch ein schönes Beispiel dafür, dass sich das Geschlecht nicht aus der Oberkategorie ableitet.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely neutral (as all letters).